# How to Download XML File from a web service with HTML like code

Tags: php, xml

I am new to PHP.  I am downloading an XML file from a web service using PHP. I can download the file using this code:

```
$sourcefile = "http...com?querystring=string";

$destinationfile = 'data\description.xml';

$xml = file_get_contents($sourcefile);

file_put_contents($destinationfile, $xml);
```

But when I open the XML file, it has `&lt;` where `<` should be and `&gt;` where `>` should be.

I added this line of code to decode it before saving it to file, which fixes the above problem:

```
$xml = html_entity_decode($xml);
```

This doesn't seem to me to be the right way to go about it.  Also, I am getting a weird piece of text showing up in the XML file, which prevents me from parsing the XML file:
`&#x1A;`

I tried using `str_replace($xml)` right before decoding it (and tried it after decoding it), but that wouldn't get rid of it.

What is the correct way to download an XML file using GET from a web service in PHP and will it get rid of that weird string (`&#x1A;`)?

Comment: You are downloading it fine. What's disturbing is if you are claiming that you, personally&physically, downloading a file results in a different file than if you download on the server. I'm confused with what you are asking.. needs more code/output.

Comment: Given the code above, you appear to be loading the api and saving the file correctly. If you are seeing the html entities on the output file, that means the api is encoding the html entities.

Comment: The XML file is created using a web service (HTTP GET) which I have no part of creating. When I view the XML file in a browser, it displays fine because the HTML code &lt to a browser is the same as <.  And &gt is the same as >.  But when I go to download it, it send it to me in the HTML form, not the form that uses <node>. So I'm wondering if there is some other way I need to be downloading it?

Comment: `<` and `&lt;` are NOT the same thing in a browser. If you loaded the api in the browser and viewed the source you would probably see the entities. Meaning saving the file from the browser would save it with the entities making it not a valid xml file. You would have to copy the contents of the page (not source) and paste into an xml file for it to work.

Comment: I deleted my answer since I was incorrect. `$xml = html_entity_decode($xml);` should do it. Can you post an example or a link to this malformed xml api?

Comment: The API is behind a password protected area.  The downloading of the XML file seems to work fine using `$xml = html_entity_decode($xml);` to format it. However, I am still getting that weird string, `&#x1A;` within the xml file which prevents me from formatting it. Is there some way to remove it before saving it?

Comment: `$xml = str_replace('&#x1A;', '', $xml);` should do the trick.